# Using C# to manipulate a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet-deployment issue

Tags: c#, excel

I have created a C# program which removes protection from a spreadsheet, locks specific cells, enables filtering and then protects the spreadsheet again (a colleague has a routine in SQL Server, I believe, that creates the spreadsheet).

I managed this using version 16 of the Microsoft Excel object library. Everything is working on my PC but I cannot get it to work on the server, where I need it.

It does not appear I can now install the PIAs on the server-I have tried the 2010 version but that still does not work.

What are my options, other than purchasing an add-on?

Thanks

Comment: If all you need to do in the server is edit those spreadsheets, I would look into the [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) library (it's open source). It's neat since it is not dependent on the Excel interop library and it's a lot faster since all it does it edit the XML without opening excel. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, I have got it working, even on the server.